# PHP apache_request_headers does not work well

Tags: php, rest, httprequest

Hello may ask this why is it that on my code i cannot obtain the headers['Authorization'] when executing my code?

coz meanwhile iv'e developed a REST API that can handle database to clients using php-json-mysql so when i use GET method together i also include my apikey into headers as 'Authorization' but i cannot fetch it in my code.

Here's my approach:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    //Good
}else {
    //API KEY is missing
}
```

but in my request header it says that

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Authorization: API_KEY
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

im using Advance REST Client extension on chrome.
anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Authorization` header has a [specific format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) it should conform to.

Since using it as

```
Authorization: API_KEY
```

is not valid, the web server is probably ignoring it altogether. You might want to use a custom header like this:

`X-Authorization: API_KEY` or

`X-Api-Key: API_KEY`

It's been a while since I've used PHP but I think if you send the header like this, you can't get them by using `apache_request_headers` so you will have to obtain it this way:

`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION']` or

`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_KEY']`

Comment: oh, work fine, i think PHP hide this header, or set to safemode=on in httpconfig hmm what you think?